# LaTeX: Arrows with text

Tags: math-mode, arrows, annotations

[image: Example picture with arrows and text below them]

How can I create arrows with a text below the arrows like in this picture? I tried it with LaTeX, but it didn't work like that in this picture.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Could you please add a little example of what you tried?

Comment: @CarLaTeX 0=x^2 {{-4x}_{\displaystyle\uparrow_{p}}}+{{3}_{\displaystyle\uparrow_{q}}}

Comment: Consider editing your question and including this snippet of code. Better yet, proivde a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
0 = x^{2}
    - \underset{\displaystyle p}{\underset{\uparrow}{4}}x
    + \underset{\displaystyle q}{\underset{\uparrow}{3}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

This is a nice use case for `stackengine`:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{stackengine}

\begin{document}
$ 0=x^2 -{} \stackMath\Shortunderstack{{4} {\uparrow} {p}}x + \stackMath\Shortunderstack{{3} {\uparrow} {q}} $
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

One of the many possible ways to add arrows in the desired manor is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
0 = x^2 - &4 \, x + 3 \\
& \uparrow  \hspace{6mm} \uparrow \\
& p \hspace{6mm} q
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

which gives the result
[image]

Answer (score 4):

A small variation of @Jasper Habicht answer:

- for arrows are used `arrows.meta` library of `tikz` package
- `\stackMath` is moved to begin of equation

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm, varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\newcommand\tikzuparrow{\tikz\draw[-{Straight Barb[scale=0.8]}] (0,0) -- ++ (0,0.5);}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stackengine}

\begin{document}
\[\stackMath
0 = x^2 - \Shortunderstack{4 {\tikzuparrow} p} x
        + \Shortunderstack{3 {\tikzuparrow} q}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

An important aspect is that the arrow and the descriptor should not add horizontal space (but it's up to you to avoid clashes in other situations).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\subdesc}[2]{%
  % #1 = main part, #2 = subdescriptor
  \begin{array}[t]{@{}c@{}}
  #1 \\
  \noalign{\vspace{-0.6ex}}
  \hidewidth \scriptstyle\uparrow \hidewidth \\
  \noalign{\vspace{-0.3ex}}
  \hidewidth #2 \hidewidth
  \end{array}%
}

\begin{document}

\[
0 = x^3 - \subdesc{4}{p}x^3 + \subdesc{3}{q}
\]

\[
0 = x^3 - \subdesc{4}{a}x^3 + \subdesc{3}{b}
\]

\[
0 = x^3 - \subdesc{4}{u-v}x^3 + \subdesc{3}{b}
\]

\end{document}
```

The arrow is in `\scriptstyle` to make it less prominent, but this requires fixing a bit the vertical spacing.

[image]